# Why do functions like isdigit() return a random non-zero value?

Tags: c, gcc

In the second edition of The C Programming Language book, it is said that functions like isdigit may return any non-zero value for true. Why do functions like isdigit return a random non-zero value for true instead of something standardized like 1 (just like logical expressions do)? Also, in my tests, the result of the isdigit function was always 2048 for true. Is this fully random or tied to something, or is this 2048 value the same for everyone?

Compiler that I use: GCC 12.1.0

Comment: It _is_ standardized. The standard is: non-zero is true, zero is false. Different library implementations are therefore able to do whatever architectural tricks and optimizations available that can result in a non-zero return value.

Comment: It means an implementation can choose any behavior they want. Whether it's 1 or 2048 or truly random, it satisfies the C standard as long as it's not zero.

Comment: `!!isdigit((unsigned char)whatever)` is always `0` or `1` with the same meaning as `isdigit((unsigned char)whatever)` ... *cast may be unnecessary*

Comment: Generally "any non-zero value" *is* considered to be true.

Comment: If you wish, you can treat it as if it returned `bool` and store the result in a `bool`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common implementation of `isdigit` and the related routines such as `isalpha` is to use an array indexed by character value in which each element of the table is a set of bit flags for the properties. There is one bit that is set if the character is a digit, one that is set if the character is a letter, one that is set if it is a white-space character, and so on.

Then the `<ctype.h>` functions can be implemented largely as `table[x] & mask`, where the mask selects the desired bit(s) for the test.

This results in a result that is zero if the character not in the tested set and non-zero if it is. Because the non-zero value is the tested flag(s), it is not one unless the applicable flag happened to use bit zero, with value one. For example, if the bit used to indicate a digit is bit ten, with value 1024, then `isdigit` will always return zero or 1024.

This suffices to serve the purposes of the character classification functions. Adding a requirement they return only one or zero would require an extra step, so it would be wasteful, and therefore this requirement was not added to the specification.

Comment: The mentioned table contains in each entry the flags for _all_ these `isXXX` functions. This saves a lot of memory, at least for small machines like the ones where C what implemented in former years.

Comment: It's "one entry per char value", not "one entry per char entry per is*() function`.